# Subquery order by not working for outer group by query in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have student documents table that store data with class and stream foreign id as following.

[image]

I want to fetch latest document from student_documents that is grouped by class and stream.

Current query and result is as below.

```
SELECT this.* FROM ( 
    SELECT * from student_documents 
    where status != 'D' 
    order by document_id desc ) this 
WHERE 1 AND(this.status!='D') 
group by fk_class_id, fk_stream_id 
order by document_id desc 
limit 0,20
```

[image]

Here Iam expecting document_id 2,3 and 5 and getting 1,3 and 4.

Comment: ORDER BY apllied in the subquery is always lost in outer query. If your subquery rowset is not order-dependent (no LIMIT, user-defined variables usage, etc.) then you may (or even must) remove ORDER BY clause from the subquery code.

Comment: What's the point of using `GROUP BY` without any aggregation functions?